# Sorting an arraylist in java without using predefined sort method

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I want to sort an arraylist by sales person name but I'm not allowed to use built-in sort.
In the followin code, I'm trying to manually sort it but it shows error (required: variable found: value) on the lines commented.

```
    int j,k;
    boolean flag = true;  
    Salesperson person = new Salesperson(null, 0, 0);

    while (flag) {
        flag = false;
        for (j = 0, k=1; j < salesperson.size()-1; j++, k++) {
            if (salesperson.get(j).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(salesperson.get(j+1).getName()) > 0) {                                             // ascending sort

                person = salesperson.get(j);
             //   salesperson.get(j) = salesperson.get(k);     
             //   salesperson.get(k) = person;
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct code. I was making mistake in theses lines

```
         //salesperson.get(j) = salesperson.get(k);     
         //   salesperson.get(k) = person;
```

these were replaced by the following lines, and now there is no error

```
                salesperson.set(j, salesperson.get(k));     
                salesperson.set(k, person);
```

Thanks for your answers

```
    int j,k;
    boolean flag = true;  // will determine when the sort is finished
    Salesperson person = new Salesperson(null, 0, 0);

    while (flag) {
        flag = false;
        for (j = 0, k=1; j < salesperson.size()-1; j++, k++) {
            if (salesperson.get(j).getName().compareToIgnoreCase(salesperson.get(j+1).getName()) > 0) {                                             // ascending sort

                person = salesperson.get(j);
                salesperson.set(j, salesperson.get(k));     
                salesperson.set(k, person);
                flag = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't sort an array in one loop , at least that's what i know , even if you got the part inside the `if` statement right , the algorithm is still wrong . You only compared each person with the adjacent person in one pass only.

Let's say you are sorting an array of numbers that looks like this :

`5 4 6 3 1 2` with this algorithm , you would have this result `4 5 3 1 2 6`

on one pass like you did it's still not sorted , only every number got compared to the adjacent one.

Also about setting a value , use `ArrayList.set()` like Eran answered .

[Here are some sorting algorithms](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/)

Comment: But it worked that way. Where is Eran's answer ? I want to vote it.

Comment: Ah somehow i missed that first loop sorry ... well yeah it would work , just correct the swapping . And my answer isn't the correct one you didn't do it in one pass .

Comment: No problem @vlatkozelka. Normally it's done using 2 for loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
//salesperson.get(j) = salesperson.get(k);     
//   salesperson.get(k) = person;
```

You are taking out the values through the get() method. That can't be used to assign values. That is why you get compilation errors.

What you should do is create a temp object and assigned to that and do the swapping of objects
But you must recheck your sorting iteration logic

Comment: Can he actually sort this way ? even if he gets the swapping right , can he actually sort in one pass like this ?!

Comment: oh ... yeah, i missed that somehow